# MySQL and Autoincrement Consistency

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I would like to grab the auto increment id of a table right after an insert.  The LAST_INSERT_ID() should work, but is it 100% full proof?  Meaning if two statements are executed at the same time in a Stored Procedure, will it use the last ID within that context, or from the other connection that was made?

```
INSERT INTO foo (auto,text)
    VALUES(NULL,'text');         # generate ID by inserting NULL
INSERT INTO foo2 (id,text)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text');  # use ID in second table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL manual says this

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

> **Important**
>       If you insert multiple rows using a single INSERT statement, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value generated for the first inserted
>   row only.  The reason for this is to make it possible to reproduce
>   easily the same INSERT statement against some other server.
>
> The value of LAST_INSERT_ID() will be consistent across all versions
>   if all rows in the INSERT or UPDATE statement were successful.
>
> The currently executing statement does not affect the value of
>   LAST_INSERT_ID().
>
> If the previous statement returned an error, the value of LAST_INSERT_ID() is undefined.  For transactional tables, if the
>   statement is rolled back due to an error, the value of
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() is left undefined.  For manual ROLLBACK, the value of
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() is not restored to that before the transaction; it
>   remains as it was at the point of the ROLLBACK.

So yes this is the best way to do so, provided you use single insert queries not grouped ones